# How to remove ranking of query results

Tags: pg-search

I have the following pg_search scope on my stories.rb model:

```
  pg_search_scope   :with_text, 
                    :against => :title, 
                    :using => { :tsearch => { :dictionary => "english" }},
                    :associated_against => { :posts => :contents }
```

I want the query to return the results ignoring any ranking (I care only about the date the story was last updated order DESC).  I know that this is an easy question for most of the people who view it, but how do I turn off the rank ordering in pg_search?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm the author of pg_search.

You could do something like this, which uses [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder)

```
MyModel.with_text("foo").reorder("updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks!  BTW, didn't need `.reorder.order("updated_at DESC")`.  Only needed `.reorder("updated_at DESC")`

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful for me too. Any way to use a published_at field instead? Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604862/pg-search-how-to-order-by-published-at-field-in-multisearchable